# How to ask for a clarification for some word

Tags: phrase-usage, politeness, connotations

For example, someone said:

> The dm said its our call

I'm new to D&D, so I don't understand what does it mean by "our call". How do you ask for that? I tried:

> What do you mean by "our call"?

But it sounds like I am thinking that the other person says bullshit. The situation is a casual discord conversation.

Is there a better way to ask for the meaning of the word? Is "What does 'our call' mean?" polite enough?

Comment: In *some* spoken contexts, *What do you mean by [that]?* can be used dismissively (implying something like *How dare you!* or *Are you trying to make unpleasant accusations?* But these are ***context-dependent*** usages - it's extremely unlikely that anyone would think of that meaning in a context where you clearly just wanted the question to be interpreted and answered ***literally***. So don't waste time and effort looking for a "non-offensive" alternative - there's no need, because the "default" phrasing ***isn't***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it sounds like I am thinking that the other person says bullshit.

It doesn't sound like that to me. It's a normal way to ask another person for elaboration. It's polite enough for a casual chat among friends.

You can make things more polite by asking indirect questions.

> Could you tell me what "our call" means?
>
> Can you please explain what you meant by "our call"?

I'd simply say

> Wait, guys! What's "our call"? What does it mean?